# Case converter from xxx xxx form to XXX Xxxx

Tags: regex

I want to know if exist a program or a regex or some trick to convert from

```
Jackson Michael
jordan michael
jordan Michael
..
```

into this form

```
JACKSON Michael
JORDAN Michael
..
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Notepad+× or some online case converter, I remember that I used sed in Windows, now I will try

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(.* .\)/\U\1/'
```

Where

- `s/.../.../` is "search and replace"
- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `.* .` matches a word+space+character chunk
- `(...)` indicates what `\1` refers to later (these parentheses need to be escaped, hence `\(` etc.)
- `\U` converts to uppercase
- `\1` refers to the first occurrence of `(...)`.

It can be described as *find a word+space+character chunk at the beginning of a line and replace it with its uppercase version (the rest of the line stays intact)*.